# How to delete multiple events in mysql 8.0 database ? it was working in 5.7 but not in 8.0?

Tags: mysql

Is there any possibilities to drop multiple events using single query ? I know, we can get list of events using show events and drop single event with there name.

In mysql 5.7 or lowest version it is possible but i am using mysql 8.0.

Comment: how do you do it MySQL 5.7 ? Add that bit to the question

Comment: Help us help you - please share the SQL statement that you used to use in 5.7 and the error you're getting in 8.0.

Comment: In 5.7 we are using below query for delete multiple events:
DELETE FROM mysql.event;

When i run this query in mysql8.0 its show s me below error:
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.event' doesn't exist

Comment: @DeepPatel similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224293/2469308 No `mysql.event` table exists now. You can read the data in temporary tables of `information_schema`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using MySQL Shell - for a one off, you can use (using Python mode):

```
mysqlsh> \py

mysql-py> i_s = session.get_schema("information_schema")

mysql-py> events = i_s.EVENTS \
       ->             .select("sys.quote_identifier(EVENT_SCHEMA) AS EventSchema", "sys.quote_identifier(EVENT_NAME) AS EventName") \
       ->             .where("EVENT_SCHEMA = 'db1'").execute().fetch_all();

mysql-py> events
[
    [
        "`db1`",
        "`event1`"
    ], 
    [
        "`db1`",
        "`event2`"
    ], 
    [
        "`db1`",
        "`event``3`"
    ]
]

mysql-py> sql_fmt = "DROP EVENT {0}.{1}"
mysql-py> for event in events:
       ->     print(sql_fmt.format(*event))
       ->     session.sql(sql_fmt.format(*event)).execute()
       ->
DROP EVENT `db1`.`event1`
DROP EVENT `db1`.`event2`
DROP EVENT `db1`.`event``3`
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.0038 sec)
```

For a more throughout explanation and examples of creating a more general purpose utility, see also https://mysql.wisborg.dk/2018/12/02/mysql-8-drop-several-stored-events-procedures-or-functions/ .